# How to paint part of an image in VB?

Tags: vb.net, image, paint, fill

VB: How to paint/fill part of an image?

Hello. Im trying to make a small game in VB. I have a map of Europe divided into countries. when you conquer a country I need the color to change to the player color. How can I fill just that part of the larger image and nothing else?

I also need to know if its possible to make a sort of "button" control so that if one reigon on the image is clicked it is "selected" and can then do an action?

Comment: How are you painting the *whole* image of the continent?

Answer (score 1):

One simple method for doing this sort of thing is to have multiple images--one for the whole continent and then one for each country.  The images for each of the country would be the same size as the one for the whole continent, but only the area where the country-in-question is colored.  For instance, the entire area outside of the country could be white and then the whole area of the country itself would be black, like a shadow, showing where the country is located in the whole-continent image.  These kinds of images are often called mask-images.

Then, when the user clicks on the main image, you can loop through all of the mask images to find which one is colored at that pixel location.  You can use the same masks, or a similar concept for overlaying or drawing a highlight over any particular country.